# Origin of the phrase, "There's more than one way to skin a cat."

Tags: etymology, phrases

The meaning is clear, but where did this phrase originate? Was it always such a gruesome reference?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I couldn't find any use of the phrase earlier than the 1840 *[Money Diggers](http://books.google.com/books?id=k3FIAQAAIAAJ&pg=RA1-PA81&dq=money%20diggers%201840&hl=en&ei=GckLTojAIord0QHa0ImGAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)* reference, but I did find some background to which the saying might refer. Apparently the debate on cat-skinning boiled down to whether or not it was done while the cat was still alive. Here's a [clip](http://books.google.com/books?id=3TkSAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA10&dq=%22skin%20a%20cat%22&hl=en&ei=L8ELTrfbJ-m30AHs1NF8&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22skin%20a%20cat%22&f=false) from the disturbing House of Commons' *Minutes of Evidence Taken Before Committee on Bill for Prevention of Cruelty to Animals*, 1832:

[image: http://books.google.com/books?id=3TkSAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA10&dq=%22skin+a+cat%22&hl=en&ei=L8ELTrfbJ-m30AHs1NF8&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22skin%20a%20cat%22&f=false]

And [here's](http://books.google.com/books?id=vjEFAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA96&dq=%22skin%20a%20cat%22&hl=en&ei=L8ELTrfbJ-m30AHs1NF8&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22skin%20a%20cat%22&f=false) confirmation from *The Leisure Hour*, 1879, that cats were used for womens' furs, but with a denial they were ever skinned alive:

[image: http://books.google.com/books?id=vjEFAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA96&dq=%22skin+a+cat%22&hl=en&ei=L8ELTrfbJ-m30AHs1NF8&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22skin%20a%20cat%22&f=false]

So, to answer your second question, yes, it was always quite gruesome.

Comment: So there are actually only two ways to skin a cat: while it's alive, or while it's dead.

Comment: @NuclearWang How many ways if it's Schrödinger's cat?

Comment: @iceman  There are two ways, one of then is you skin a cat (cause you are a bad person), the other is you don't skin a cat (you are nice or the cat never existed).  The third one (wait!) is both, you skin a cat and, at the same time, you don't skin it.

Comment: I find your use of "boiled down", in this context, disturbing.

Answer (score 12):

> There are many versions of this proverb, which suggests there are
>   always several ways to do something.      The earliest printed
>   citation of this proverbial saying that I can find is in a short story
>   by the American humorist Seba Smith - The Money Diggers, 1840:
>
> "There are more ways than one to skin a cat," so are there more ways
>   than one of digging for money.      Charles Kingsley used one old
>   British form in Westward Ho! in 1855: “there are more ways of killing
>   a cat than choking it with cream”. Other versions include “there are
>   more ways of killing a cat than by choking it with butter”, and “there
>   are more ways of killing a dog than choking him with pudding”. The
>   earliest version appears as far back as 1678, in the second edition of
>   John Ray’s collection of English proverbs, in which he gives it as
>   “there are more ways to kill a dog than hanging”.
>
> Mark Twain used your version in A Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur’s
>   Court in 1889: “she was wise, subtle, and knew more than one way to
>   skin a cat”, that is, more than one way to get what she wanted. An
>   earlier appearance is in ’Way down East; or, Portraitures of Yankee
>   Life by Seba Smith of about 1854: “This is a money digging world of
>   ours; and, as it is said, ‘there are more ways than one to skin a
>   cat,’ so are there more ways than one of digging for money”. From the
>   way he writes, the author clearly knew this to be a well-known
>   existing proverbial saying.
>
> Writers have pointed to its use in the southern states of the US in
>   reference to the catfish, often abbreviated to cat, a fish that is
>   indeed usually skinned in preparing it for eating. However, it looks
>   very much from the multiple versions of the saying, their wide
>   distribution and their age, that this is just a local application of
>   the proverb.
>
> The version more than one way to skin a cat seems to have nothing
>   directly to do with the American English term to skin a cat, which is
>   to perform a gymnastic exercise that involves passing the feet and
>   legs between the arms while hanging by the hands from a horizontal
>   bar. That name may have been suggested by the action of turning an
>   animal’s skin inside out as part of the process of removing it from
>   the body.
>
> Other forms of end that have been employed (and sometimes of a dog
>   rather than a cat) are hanging, choking with butter and choking with
>   pudding.

taken from [Origin of there is more than one way to skin a cat](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-mor1.htm)

Comment: "There are more ways to kill a cat than choking it with cream" (and dogs/puddings) might indicate excessive labour or expense in doing a fairly simple but possibly unpleasant task: why spend out on cream instead of simply knocking it on the head? This is a subtly different and richer meaning than simply "There are different ways of doing that".

Answer (score 12):

The [1840](http://books.google.com/books?id=k3FIAQAAIAAJ&pg=RA1-PA81&dq=money%20diggers%201840&hl=en&ei=GckLTojAIord0QHa0ImGAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) *Money Diggers* reference was also the earliest I found for this exact phrase, although I found some earlier variants.

---

### 1839: *"There's more ways to kill a cat than one"*

Here's a letter from John Smith dated [March 13, 1839](http://books.google.fi/books?id=CGIqAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA91&dq=%22ways%20*%20a%20cat%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qjuRT8bPM8TP4QSE1OCHBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22kill%20a%20cat%22&f=false):

[image: But come to look round we couldn t find any thing to make a flag of truce of for Sargent Johnson said it must be white and we hadn t one of us got a white handkerchief or any sich thing so we seemed to be kind of stuck At last says I You needn't bother about that There's more ways to kill a cat than one So I tore off a good large square piece of my shirt and tied it on to the end of my gun and says I Sargent I m ready]

---

### 1836: *"there are more ways of drawing a cat out of a well than by the bucket!"*

From [1836](http://books.google.com/books?id=gDElAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA53&dq=%22ways%20*%20a%20cat%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qjuRT8bPM8TP4QSE1OCHBA&ved=0CEgQ6AEwAw) *The Priors of Prague* by William Johnson Neale:

[image: It is not so easy to blowup a dog thought I though to be sure recalling an old Spanish proverb there are more ways of drawing a cat out of a well than by the bucket But courage good heart thou hast not hitherto failed me and for the present I will just take a stare at this old city while the light remains Then for an humble supper and trust to my guitar for a bed]

---

### 1721: *"There are more ways to the Woods than one"*

Another, listed in proverb books as early as [1721](http://books.google.com/books?id=BEgOAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA319&dq=%22more%20ways%20*%20than%20one%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=o0iRT823DKfR4QSzhLWSBA&ved=0CJsBEOgBMBE4jAE) and [1732](http://books.google.com/books?id=3y8JAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA210&dq=%22more%20ways%20*%20than%20one%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=o0iRT823DKfR4QSzhLWSBA&ved=0CIQBEOgBMA04jAE) can be found in John Vanbrugh's 1721 comedy, *Esop*:

[image: There are more ways to the Woods than one. you see]

---

### 1709: *"there are more ways to Heaven than one"*

Another oft-repeated phrase of similar meaning can be found in a sermon by John Needham from [1709](http://books.google.fi/books?id=nNpbAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA16&dq=%22more%20ways%20*%20than%20one%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yUGRT-veKKOC4gSjsYyNBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22more%20ways%22&f=false):

[image: That the Command of trying the Spirits, gives them a Licence of frequenting all Assemblies ; And, that there are more ways to Heaven than One.]

---

### 1712: *"Well! more ways may be found than one, To kill a Witch that Will not drown."*

Although used literally, this humorous poem called *The Fair Nun, A Tale* by Elijah Fenton was reprinted many times in the 18th and 19th centuries, the earliest I found from [1712](http://books.google.com/books?id=YEkJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA219&dq=%22more%20ways%20*%20than%20one%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yUGRT-veKKOC4gSjsYyNBA&ved=0CEsQ6AEwBDigAQ).

[image: And twas in truth a proper Notion But still it kept the Elastic Motion Well more ways may be found than one To kill a Witch that Will not drown]

---

Answer (score 6):

According to [The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/there-is-more-than-one-way-to-skin-a-cat.html):

> The earliest printed citation of this proverbial saying that I can find is in a short story by the American humorist Seba Smith - The Money Diggers, 1840:
>
> *"There are more ways than one to skin a cat," so are there more ways than one of digging for money.*

Answer (score 1):

"Their is more then one way to skin a cat" is not referencing the removal of flesh from our feline friends ,but rather a phrase that originated from the Mississippi river region that pertains to the preparation of a catfish.

Comment: Any references?

Comment: As @Ashu says above, this seems to be a later appropriation of an existing proverb rather than its origin.

Comment: @metal .  A Mississippi resident would never appropriate the property of others. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I had a different idea about the saying "skinning cats." I thought it was about using the cat of nine tails in the British Navy. It meant there are many ways to flog someone.

Comment: Is this just an idea, or do you have evidence to back this up?