# origin of the expression "there is more than one way to skin a cat"

Tags: etymology, expressions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Origin of the phrase, “There's more than one way to skin a cat.”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32123/origin-of-the-phrase-theres-more-than-one-way-to-skin-a-cat)

what is the origin of the expression "there is more than one way to skin a cat"? I can't find a good reference for it.