# Euphemism for "There's more than one way to skin a cat"

Tags: phrases, euphemisms

Growing up in the 80s, I ended up hearing/using this phrase a lot whenever I wanted to express that there was more than one way to do something: "there's more than one way to skin a cat."

I have recently been in situations where I need to express the same thing, but am realizing that the phrase is actually quite grotesque. Is there a well-known euphemism to express the same thing - that there is more than one way to get something done?

[This](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32123/origin-of-the-phrase-theres-more-than-one-way-to-skin-a-cat) question is slightly related, but only asks for the origins:

Comment: I suspect that [“there are more ways to kill a dog than hanging”](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-mor1.htm) will also be deemed unacceptable :)

Comment: Someone who's first language is not english once quoted it as "there's more than one way to peel a cat". :-)

Comment: I'm wondering if there actually IS more than one way to skin a cat. How many ways could there be?

Comment: From the head or tail, etc. With a knife or razor, etc. You get the idea.

Comment: Not the same expression at all, but I heard a rather satisfying alternative to "kill two birds with one stone": "light two candles with one flame."

Comment: Disclaimer:  I am a cat lover.  Now:  I've taken to using a variation on the dermis-and-feline-flaying locution.  I say, "There's more than one way to swing a dead cat!"  A book published a number of years ago now was titled (I think) "101 Uses for a Dead Cat"?  I think that book kind of stimulated my thinking in this regard.  By the way, my favorite way to swing a dead cat is by its tail.  What's your fave?

Comment: You can say *there's more than one way to peel a cat* only if your English is a little rusted.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you don't like the graphic reference to feline taxidermy, you can substitute just about any verb-noun pair to get your point across, so long as your audience can imagine more than one way to do it.  These aren't common idioms by any means (some of them will register a tiny number of hits in a Google book search, and others won't), but one could say:

> *There's more than one way to bake a cake...
>
>   There's more than one way to cook an egg...
>
>   There's more than one way to peel an orange...
>
>   There's more than one way to make a bed...
>
>   There's more than one way to catch a rabbit...
>
>   There's more than one way to shear a sheep...
>
>   There's more than one way to shoe a horse...
>
>   There's more than one way to shine a penny...
>
>   There's more than one way to knit a sweater...
>
>   There's more than one way to dive into a pool...
>
>   There's more than one way to shake a carbuncle*...<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> That last one may sound a bit odd, but I actually found it in a [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=pvwQ669Ks8EC&pg=PA173&lpg=PA173&dq=%22more%20than%20one%20way%20to%20shake%20a%20carbuncle%22&source=bl&ots=dQvdBrBKWt&sig=gleY1KG1z32xcenQrYxUcWOxs68&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eSCtULPdPLDW0gGnjYHYBg&sqi=2&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22more%20than%20one%20way%20to%20shake%20a%20carbuncle%22&f=false).

Comment: Thanks, I've heard of some of these, and I'm sure that anyone I'm talking to might have as well, so marking this as the right answer. Do you know if any of these are more popular than the rest?

Comment: Figuring out which are more popular is tricky. We can do a search like [this one](http://www.google.com/#q=%22more+than+one+way+to+crack+a+nut%22&hl=en&safe=active&tbo=d&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&bpcl=38897761&biw=1078&bih=731), but we can't simply count results. ("More than one way to frost a cake" found in a cookbook, e.g., wouldn't really count as a euphamism – not if the book was explaining how to frost a cake!) That said, "cook an egg" & "peel an orange (or apple, or potato)" may be more common than the others, but sometimes originalty is better than triteness in cases like this.

Comment: Go for the most generic/meta: "there's more than one way to verb a noun."

Comment: All these (and many more) will doubtless turn up from time to time.  But unless I'm much mistaken, they're *all* consciously "recast" from OP's original. On the other hand, if you really were bothered about the imagery of that original, I suppose you could say these are all effectively "euphemisms" for it.

Comment: Who shines their pennies?

Comment: @AdamRobinson: Coin collectors, maybe? (BTW, who skins their cats?) :^)

Comment: Note that you can also use all of those verbs while retaining the original noun 'cat'. Except perhaps 'make'.

Comment: @naught101 More than one way to dive into a cat!? O.o

Comment: @jackweirdy: What? Are you gonna try to argue that there's *only* one way? :D

Comment: @naught101: I think jackweirdy was adding _dive_ to your list of exceptions that don't work with _cat_. I was going to add _knit_ to that list, too, but then I [thought better of it](http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3090/2685870767_d104598f7e_o.jpg). But I would like to add _shoe_ to that list. (Then again, maybe I'm wrong about [that](http://www.funnycutestuff.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/cat-wearing-shoes.jpg), too.)

Comment: @J.R. +1 for citing sources....

Comment: @naught101: Ouch! Proof that barbarism is in the eye (or the knitting needle) of the beholder. Somehow, I can see that image going viral, and even perhaps inspiring a horror film...

Answer (score 35):

Dermis and feline can be divorced by manifold methods.

Give it time; it'll catch on.

Comment: aw, c'mon downvoter!  That's funny!

Comment: He wanted a euphemism.

Comment: +1. I can't ever see this catching on, but this is funny. :D

Comment: @Suman I'm sure that's what most people thought they first time they heard the one about fecal matter and rotatory impellers.

Comment: @Kristina Lopez: But it's not an *answer* in any meaningful sense. I expect a mod will soon convert this one to a *comment*, after which I might upvote it myself.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It takes the edge off the original expression, euphemistically. It's the same relationship between the euphemism "When the S%$# hits the fan" and the counter-euphemism "When the excrement hits the rotatory impellers."

Comment: It's still non-standard, so unsuitable for ELU, despite the upvotes.

Answer (score 11):

Considering that the OP is in the IT industry, the following [suggestion from Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TIMTOWTDI) might be pertinent:

> TIMTOWTDI
>   (Internet) *There is more than one way to do it* (a motto of the Perl programming language).

The saying, "*Where there's a will, there's a way*", might also work in the right context.

Comment: Nice! But like you said, it probably only makes sense in the IT industry, and may not be known by people who haven't touched Perl. This is a good one though. :)

Comment: @Suman. It's a perfectly normal English sentence, and makes sense in any context. It might be an *idiom* to Perl programmers only, but it's understandable by anyone.

Comment: Ah right, sorry. "There is more than one way to do it" makes perfect sense, TIMTOWDI doesn't. I was thinking of the latter when I posted the comment.

Comment: The Perl community commonly abbreviates the phrase to TIMTOWDI, but I've never seen the abbreviation used in the wild. Shame, though, because it is succinct and pronounceable and the base phrase is used widely.

Comment: And how exactly would you pronounce TIMTOWTDI without sending people into fits of snickering laughter?

Answer (score 7):

"I have more than one trick up my sleeve"

Comment: Now that *is* an answer! As with my *irons in the fire* and @Autoresponder's *strings to one's bow*, though, they all tend to imply you *already have* an alternative ready to deploy. Whereas OP's version often means *we can figure out another way to solve this problem*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I totally agree but more often than not, for me at least, that other trick up my sleeve is more wishful thinking than actionable plan! lol!

Answer (score 4):

"There are other fish in the sea" is a possibility. Even though the implication may be that of a relationship, it doesn't have to be.

You could also stick with the feline reference with:

> There's more than one way to scare a cat.

Also:

> There's more than one way to eat a pie.
>   There's more than one way to crack an egg.
>   There's more than one way to beat an egg.

Of course, you could always fall back on the always witty:

> That's not the only way.
>   There's more than one way to do that.
>   There's a better way.

Comment: **OR** - just *"**or**"** (followed by one or more alternative methods of solving the problem! :)

Answer (score 3):

What about ["all roads lead to Rome"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_roads_lead_to_Rome)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to say you're prepared/armed with multiple options,the phrase ["*to have many strings to one's bow*"](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/42/messages/1376.html) is  relevant. It refers to a state of 'being prepared with back-up plans to deal with contingencies.'

Answer (score 1):

Slightly less gruesome, but still related, is the proverb "There are more ways of killing a cat than choking it with cream."

Comment: I've never heard that. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

*There is more than one way to tie a shoelace*.

I like this, but it is only really relevant if the 'outcome' that is being referred to is the same, in this case, "a tied shoelace".

In the case of the "skin a cat" phrase, the manner in which the cat gets skinned is dependent upon the reason for skinning the cat - if the intention is to have an intact skin for taxidermy, then the method employed might be different than if the intention is to have a 'skinned cat', in which case one isn't really too worried about how intact the skin is following the skinning process.

You could substitute 'tie a shoelace' for 'tie a knot' in this case I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to brew your coffee.

Answer (score 0):

Re: *Is there a well-known euphemism to express the same thing - that there is more than one way to get something done?*

Why yes, namely *"There is more than one way to get something done."*

Answer (score 0):

> More than one road to Timbuktu

Some of the other suggestions on here have been a bit questionable in that they suggest a misunderstanding of the nuance of usage of the idioms proffered. Be careful if you are a non-native speaker that you are understanding things correctly before submitting, or to put it another way, as my old English teacher used to say, "engage brain before opening mouth".

Comment: Your teacher capitalized every single word? In *speech*? I applaud his dedication. Seriously though, you don't even know who on this page is a native speaker and who isn't. In fact I'm not sure I am seeing a single non-native speaker here, certainly not among the top answers. More to the point though, native speakers misuse idioms, too. All the time. (They are in fact prone to making certain horrible mistakes no non-native speaker ever would. But I digress.)

Answer (score 0):

There's the right way, the wrong way, and there's the Army way.
Or,
There's the right way, the wrong way, and there's my way.

Comment: Why do you think this answers the question?