# Synonyms for Vomit?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, synonyms

I am trying to find a synonym for the word "vomit" in its **noun** form. There are plenty of words used to express the action of ejecting matter from the stomach, but the only word I can find that refers to the **actual material ejected** is "vomit". I was hoping for a more formal word, but that seems near to impossible since I cannot even find informal ways to say it. I specifically am describing a murder in nineteenth century England which involves a poison that causes muscle spasms (and vomiting).

I checked thesaurus.com, macmillandictionary.com, merriam-webster.com, and Google's dictionary, but the only word provided was "vomit". Any ideas?

Comment: I'm curious to know what you're writing about where you're concerned about overusing the word "vomit"?

Comment: It is a story that includes a murder in nineteenth century England. There is poison involved which causes muscle spasms (including stomach spasms).

Comment: It should be mentioned that the most innocuous-sounding term in common use is "throw up" (though mostly as a verb).

Comment: See also: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/regurgitate – there are some derived noun forms, such as *regurgitant* and *regurgitation*, which might or might not mean what you're looking for.

Comment: Did you try a thesaurus?

Comment: @Mitch I did, the question states this fact

Comment: @CardinalSystem I don't think you're using it right if you only got a single word, the one you submitted. Try 'vomit synonyms'. You'll get what Kristina did for you.

Comment: There's also the more specifically medical 'emesis', and then for vomiting blood there's 'hematemesis', in case the poison is particularly strong and causes stomach ulcers.

Comment: _OED_ has these synonyms for the noun _vomit_ in the historical thesaurus: spew, spewing, parbreak (rare), voment (obs. rare.), vomiture (obs), vome (obs. rare.), vomiting, vomitus, chunder (austral. slang), sick, puke

Comment: A **pavement pizza**! Yum...

Comment: A **technicolor yawn**!

Comment: It's not necessarily formal, but **lunch** is always a fun one. "The victim was found in a pool of blood, feces, and yesterday's **lunch**."

Comment: *"It's possible, pig. I might be bluffing. It's conceivable, you miserable vomitous mass."* – [*TPB*](https://youtu.be/qF0uaI4GxDU?t=102)

Comment: 'Mess' on the pavement

Comment: Related: [Flaying Foxes and Vomiting People](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/336331/flaying-foxes-and-vomiting-people)

Comment: @ermanen *chunder* is also used in the UK, almost exclusively as a verb

Comment: Still a verb, but following this led me to "barking at the ants" which is now my new favorite. "Calling for O'Reilly" is a close 2nd.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not unheard of to nounify a verb so you might be able to use:

> ***Puke***: He was found lifeless, lying in a pool of his own puke.
>
> ***Upchuck***: The volume of upchuck was astounding...who could possibly have so much food and liquid in their stomach at one time?

And kinda related...***bile***.  The liquid, non-food specific stomach acid that is sometimes ejected after a person has no more food in their stomach but the spasms continue to push out the contents of the stomach.

[Per MW-Online's definition of vomit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/puke):

> **Synonyms**
>
> barf, gag, heave, hurl, vomit, retch, spew, spit up, throw up, upchuck...of these, the following can be used in a nounified version: ***barf***, ***spit up***, ***throw up***, (and as mentioned above, ***upchuck***)

Comment: Merriam-Webster is going to be skewed to US synonyms, which might not be appropriate for the 1800s in England, which @cardinalsystem added in comments. Specifically ‘barf’ and ‘upchuck’ would be very jarring.

Comment: @Spagirl Depends on whether the word is being used in dialogue or description. The latter doesn't necessarily have to be in period language (although it depends on the overall style of the novel).

Comment: Minor correction - bile is the alkaline fluid stored in the gall bladder which helps to break down fats in the digestive tract.  It is not always present in vomit but may be present when the stomach has already been emptied or when there is a particularly violent contraction of the abdominal muscles.

Comment: *Puke* is often used as a noun in British English

Comment: I disagree a bit about "gag", because one person can gag wthout puking. :x

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - to be clear, that's MW-O's list of synonyms for "vomit", though I agree with you.  When I think of someone gagging, I think of coming short of actually vomiting.

Comment: The OED has puke as a noun, earliest attestation 1705: "in *Wks. Monsieur Voiture* II. 177   With perpetual Sweating they smelt as sour as a Parish-child wallowing in its own Puke." Early usages are mostly just as crude as the word's modern connotations.

Comment: I like upchuck!

Comment: @ChrisH I agree about "puke". But I think the most common alternative noun to "vomit", used in Britain would be "sick". - "Don't tread in that sick on the pavement". But I did rather enjoy Kristina's "upchuck".

Comment: @WS2 - wow!  That's not something we say here in the US.  Sounds funny to me! :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez We all love "upchuck", Kristina. Now *how much upchuck could an upchuck chuck if an upchuck could chuck up. As much upchuck as an upchuck could chuck if a upchuck could chuck up*. Or something like that!

Comment: @WS2 you may well be right, but I reckon the distinction is one of register, perhaps leading to to a correlation between *puke* and alcohol (i.e. *puke* is the word you'd use with people you'd go drinking with).

Comment: @KristinaLopez We will often say someone "feels sick", or "they have just been sick". This will mean more than just that they feel generally ill (although it can also mean that). But specifically "to feel sick" or to "be sick" can, and often does, mean that the person feels they are going to vomit, or have just vomited. That may be uniquely British usage of "sick", I'm not sure.

Answer (score 24):

[Vomitus](https://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/mobileart.asp?articlekey=33157)

> Matter from the stomach that has come up into and may be ejected beyond the mouth, due to the act of vomiting.

Comment: Not sure there's much gained from using "vomitus" instead of "vomit".

Comment: @Barmar OP said, "I was hoping for a more formal word." It's the medical term.

Comment: @Barmar: In addition to being a more standard medical term, *vomitus* is unambiguously the material while *vomit* may also refer to the action.

Comment: Further, *vomitus*, perhaps because of it's formality and the modern use of *vomit (n)*, feels a little old-fashioned.

Comment: If I read "vomitus" in a novel, I'd think the author was just trying to sound smart, rather than using it for the sake of the novel

Comment: @millman97 It was used in the novel _Trainspotting,_ when the protagonist was going through heroin withdrawal: "One bucket for urine, one for faeces, and one for vomitus." I didn't think it made him sound particularly smart.

Comment: @millman97 What's the problem with an author trying to sound smart?

Comment: It's just my own preference, but I think if an author occasionally uses words or phrases that seem like they're trying too hard to sound smart and it doesn't fit with the rest of their style, it can be quite jarring and can ruin passages. This is especially so for words like this where I can't see why someone would use vomitus over vomit :/ however the author might surprise me and make it work, if so, fair enough :D

Comment: @millman97 it might make sense in a work of fiction that a given character would use that term.

Answer (score 17):

As you noted on comments that your context was a story set in England, I’d suggest the noun ‘**sick**’.

Defined in the OED as

> ‘vomited matter’

it is a common British-English usage. The examples from the OED however only go back to the late 1950s so it may not be historically accurate for your 19th century setting.

The OED also includes ‘**Spewing** n.’ as

> ‘Matter spewed out or vomited; spew.’

with examples from 1380 to 1880. Be aware though that the only example they give later than 1553 is from a glossary of words from County Antrim and County Down in the north of Ireland:

> *Spuans*, what is vomited

The 1811 Dictionary of the Vulgar Tongue ‘A DICTIONARY OF BUCKISH SLANG, UNIVERSITY WIT, AND PICKPOCKET ELOQUENCE’ has a number of colourful phrases for the act of spewing:

> To cast up one's accounts
>
> To cascade
>
> To shoot the cat:- to vomit from drunkenness
>
> To flash the hash
>
> To flay (or to flea) the fox
>
> To pump ship

But seems to lack any word other than ‘vomit’ for the ejected contents. The preponderance of ‘x the y’ phrase alternatives in an historical source but not stand alone nouns suggests that its unlikely that there is a swath of nouns waiting to be found.

Comment: *To cast up one's accounts* is probably the most common of this list, but really doesn't lend itself to a noun use.

Comment: I realised that but after editing down my comment it didn't come across. It could still be a useful phrase for the OP and lends itself to expanding on the accounts that have been cast up, but there doesn't seem to be an established noun version

Answer (score 11):

Though not a term you'd hear outside the medical community, **"regurgitated gastric contents"** refers to what is thrown up from the stomach of any animal, including human beings.

- Esomeprazole and Discoloration of **Regurgitated Gastric Contents** in Infants [**1**](http://repository.ubn.ru.nl/handle/2066/172543)
- Patients recovering from anaesthesia are normally nursed on the side so that **regurgitated gastric contents** do not pool in the posterior pharynx but are cleared with the aid of gravity. [**2**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=pkpWBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=%22regurgitated+gastric+contents%22&source=bl&ots=Lo4ibx74k2&sig=LpQlsSGrOxZ4B3TsPMvDS5fWqgI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu1rmr0ZTYAhWBS5AKHYtWAVI4ChDoAQg_MAU#v=onepage&q=%22regurgitated%20gastric%20contents%22&f=false)
- Anaesthesia and sedation depress or block the functioning of protective upper airway reflexes, making pulmonary aspiration of vomited or **regurgitated gastric contents** likely. [**3**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=JRkyBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA400&lpg=PA400&dq=%22regurgitated+gastric+contents%22&source=bl&ots=uu3fXbCF3o&sig=zWsYFOg2W2-lKanfAlZQZKg9L4c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu1rmr0ZTYAhWBS5AKHYtWAVI4ChDoAQhEMAY#v=onepage&q=%22regurgitated%20gastric%20contents%22&f=false)

If you write about the "post-mortem" of a character, the  medical examiner might use that term.

Comment: [wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/regurgitant) : "Noun *regurgitant* (countable and uncountable, plural regurgitants) That which has been regurgitated; vomit." - [oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/regurgitant) : "*regurgitant* adjective. Medicine. Of or relating to regurgitation; characterized or accompanied by regurgitation."

Comment: The polite word for vomit is regurgitate. OP should work around that, one way or another, unless they want to opt for [a word that no one's ever heard of](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/422930/68817) (emesis).

Comment: @Mazura   The OP is asking for a noun. "Regurgitant" is an adjective and "regurgitate" is a verb.  In medicine, when we refer to the material thrown up from the stomach, we say the "regurgitated gastric contents", a fixed phrase.  Believe  me, or [check](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/regurgitate)

Comment: regurgitation : noun (I just like the sound of regurgitant ;)

Comment: As a native speaker of Greek I want to point out that emesis usually describes the process. My English dictionary agrees, defining: ‚the action or process of vomiting‘.

Comment: @Ludi  That's what I understand.  Emesis means vomiting.  It's a common symptom during early pregnancy and, if severe or prolonged, we call it hyperemesis gravidarum.

Answer (score 9):

Courtesy of [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emesis)

### emesis

> **noun**  eme·sis  \ ˈe-mə-səs , i-ˈmē- \
>
> an act or instance of vomiting

A formal medical term that was used by British doctors in the 19th century.
From Google Books we have the following examples, *[Medical Record](https://books.google.it/books?id=TVDlAAAAMAAJ&q=emesis%20gravidarum&dq=emesis%20gravidarum&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwih2bukl5bYAhVEUBQKHRkZDx4Q6AEIQDAG)*,  1890

> Much has been written of late years on the subject of the vomiting of pregnancy and its most aggravated form, **hyperemesis** gravidarum, or uncontrollable vomiting.

and from *[THE BRITISH JOURNAL OF <del>MEMOEOPATHY</del> HOMŒOPATHY. VOL. XXXI.](https://books.google.it/books?id=nvcEAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA1-PA52&dq=%22some%20emesis%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd_5zezZbYAhXIvxQKHd97ChcQ6AEINjAD#v=onepage&q=%22some%20emesis%22&f=false)* 1873

> The heart's action was feeble, but not increased in frequency. There was no perspiration in any part of the body. The feet and whole lower extremities were cold and palsied, and hung powerless over the father's lap, in marked contrast to the rest of the body, which was so much agitated. There had been **some emesis** from the emetics given, but not free; a tablespoonful of a tablespoon of mustard and another of salt were immediately mixed with some warm water, and pressing the tongue strongly down I attempted to make the child swallow it;

Comment: The typo in the title is not mine but that of Google Books, hence the strikethrough. I can see why  GB interpreted the letter  H as an M, but how it confused the letter O in HO as ME is a little bewildering.

Comment: @Mazura it's a typo, scroll to the book cover, that's why I used the œ letter.

Comment: This answer looks the best for what the OP is after.

Comment: As a Greek I have to welcome your suggestion. However it seems that the English word, like the Greek one, describes the process not the ejected matter.

Answer (score 7):

Not specifically a synonym for vomit, but more of a euphemism:  ***[effluvium](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/effluvium)***.

> 2 : a by-product especially in the form of waste
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/effluvium)*</sub>

Being from the Latin for "the act of flowing out", it seems appropriate as a more genteel description of the result of involuntary regurgitation.

Answer (score 5):

Ejecta.

From Merriam-Webster.com: Matter (as vomit) ejected from the body.

This is the 'medical definition'.  Is also used for other ejections, such as from a volcano.

Answer (score 4):

Oxford Thesaurus of English:

> **vomit**, verb
>
> 1. *he desperately wanted to vomit*: be sick, spew, spew up, fetch up; heave, retch, reach, gag; *N. Amer.* get sick; informal
>      throw up, puke, chunder, chuck up, hurl, pray to the porcelain god, do
>      the technicolor yawn, keck, ralph; *Brit. informal* honk, shoot the cat,
>      vom; *Scottish informal* boke; *N. Amer. informal* barf, spit up, upchuck,
>      blow chunks, toss one's cookies, blow chunks; *Austral./NZ informal* go
>      for the big spit, play the whale, yodel, perk; *archaic* regorge, purge,
>      brake, cascade; *rare* egurgitate.
> 2. *I vomited my breakfast all over the
>      car*: regurgitate, bring up, spew up, heave up, cough up; *Medicine*
>      reject, lose; informal chuck up, throw up, puke; *Brit. informal* sick
>      up; *N. Amer. informal* spit up; archaic regorge, void.
> 3. *the printer is
>      vomiting folds of perforated paper*: eject, issue, emit, expel, send
>      forth, discharge, disgorge, spout, throw out, cast out, spew out,
>      belch; rare disembogue, eruct.
>
> **vomit**, noun
>
> *the front of his jacket was stained with vomit*: sick; *technical* vomitus, ejecta; *informal* chunder, puke, spew, pavement
>   pizza, technicolor yawn, liquid laugh; *N. Amer. informal* barf,
>   upchuck; *archaic* purge, parbreak.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The classic Technicolor Yawn...

Comment: @Fuhrmanator sounds like a cover band.

Comment: +1 for "liquid laugh" - I haven't heard that one for years!

Comment: Where's the one about *driving the porcelain bus* ? :)

Comment: @CaiusJard or *praying at the porcelain altar*

Comment: (I realise we've strayed into verbs now but) I always quite liked *"shouting soup"* and *"calling for Huey"*

Comment: How is this answer helpful?  OP said he wants a different noun than *vomit*.

Comment: And that's the list of synonyms one could use instead. So, why the downvote?

Answer (score 3):

> **chyme**
>   [kahym]
>   noun/
>
> the semifluid mass into which food is converted by gastric secretion and which passes from the stomach into the small intestine.
>
> [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/chyme)
>
> **bolus**
>   [boh-luh s]
>   noun/
>
> 2. a soft, roundish mass or lump, especially of chewed food.
>
> [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bolus)

Answer (score 3):

> I was hoping for a more formal word…. I specifically am describing a murder in nineteenth century England which involves a poison that causes muscle spasms (and vomiting).

The most likely term in a formal context in this period is *vomit*. That's a word used in medical texts of the time, as you can see if you look at [this search](https://www.google.ie/search?q=%22vomit%22&lr=lang_en&dcr=0&tbs=lr:lang_1en,cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_3Y6YsZjYAhUqL8AKHTQCCtAQpwUIIQ&biw=1507&bih=828&dpr=1) and filter manually for the noun usages.

If you really need a more formal word, then *vomitus* would also have been understood in this sense, particularly if one was examining its consistency, so it would be plausible in a forensic sense.

A prissy (rather than formal) use might favour *ejecta* or even *chyme* (though strictly once if it was still in your stomach to potentially be vomited it was not yet chyme, so it certainly shouldn't be used in a formal sense unless perhaps you are putting words in the mouth of a character given to hypercorrection).

The act of vomiting (rather than the contents vomited) might be referred to as *emesis*.

Answer (score 3):

**Sick**

[Collins definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sick)

Possibly restricted to British English.  But the following would be perfectly acceptable

> He woke up feeling terrible, fully clothed with his shoes covered in
>   sick

Acceptable in language terms, that is.

Answer (score 2):

For a 19th Century setting, you want something professional sounding and descriptive.  A lot of the answers here are relatively modern and slang-laden - things I couldn't see an educated doctor saying.

I'd suggest something along the lines of

> The body was found, wracked from his undoubted painful end, **ejectum** spreading from between his clenched teeth...

or

> He was found on his bed, a foul smelling, creamy **ambergris** caked around his lips....

or

> He had **refluxed** his last meal, in a stream of sickly bile...

Comment: Ambergris? Is he a whale?

Comment: @JonHanna No.  It's just an emotive descriptive term.  In the same way that someone with "a heart of ice", doesn't actually have a heart made out of ice...

Comment: Ambergris is highly valued. One would have to be deeply infatuated with someone to think of vomit caked around their lips as ambergris.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bring-sth-up)

**Bring up, bring something up**

> She was crying so much I thought she'd bring up her breakfast.

A polite, British English, phrasal verb.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with 'stomach contents' in your situation or '[former stomach contents](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vomit)' or 'partially digested matter' or something to that effect. Describing it would probably be more profitable than trying to fit a modern word into an older context.

Maybe 'last night's supper' or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

**Puke**

Puke is a good, commonly used noun for vomit (the product of the act) since at least the 17th century. (Used in Shakespeare's play *As You Like It* in 1600)

Comment: Used by Shakespeare as a verb though. [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/puke) says that *puke* meaning the "vomit matter" was not used until 1960s

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I agree.  I checked the text of "As You Like It" online for "puk" and only found "Mewling and puking in the nurse's arms."